# Libertine Font Greek Letters Size

Tags: fontsize, greek, libertine

As you can see the greek letters from pxfonts are bigger than the numbers. How can i fix the size? The numbers size is the better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lining]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine, cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{pxmi}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{18}

\begin{document}

$5\beta +5\gamma+ 2\theta+3\Gamma + 250\log_2 n = 75\sin x $

\end{document}
```

Comment: note that the height of "l" in "log" is the same as the height of the "Gamma".  the digits are shorter than tall letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `npxmi` rather than `pxmi`, since the former has better metrics. Moreover it allows to set a scaling factor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lining]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine, cmintegrals]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\def\npxmath@scaled{.94767}
\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{npxmi}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{18}

\begin{document}

$5\beta +5\gamma+ 2\theta+3\Gamma+ 250\log_2 n = 75\sin x $

\end{document}
```

The scaling factor 0.94767 has been computed by not setting `\npxmath@scaled` and measuring the height of `\beta` and of `\Gamma`: I got 6.88pt for `\beta` and 6.52pt for `\Gamma`. With the scaling factor set, I get 6.52pt for both.

[image]

Comment: thanks. i have one more question. if i add \DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}..., this give me italic font. how can i make it uppercase. Also do you think  it is convenient setting the factor ".9" instead of ".94767".

Comment: @mert I think it better not to tamper with the fonts; by default the uppercase (upright) Gamma is not taken from the same font as the lowercase Greek letters. If I use the correct font, which should be `npxmia`, I don't get a really different glyph: just the final serif is slightly different.

Comment: @mert Note that the serifs in `\Gamma` are similar to the ones in Libertine, while the `\Gamma` from the `pxmath` font has a different serif.